# changed editText in listView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Good evening everyone,
My plan is, to get back the value of a changed editText which has been filled by a listview. So far, I can see the changed value by the addTextChangedListener function in the Adapter but I don’t know how to give the value back to the main class.
This is my adapter class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hobbyathletes.hobbyathletes.R;


public class EventRefAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] string_myeventref;
private final String[] string_myeventref_value;

public EventRefAdapter(Activity context, String[] string_myeventref, String[] string_myeventref_value) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_myeventref, string_myeventref);

    this.context = context;
    this.string_myeventref = string_myeventref;
    this.string_myeventref_value = string_myeventref_value;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_myeventref, null, true);
        holder.txtname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_myeventref_name);
        holder.edtxtvalue = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_myeventref_value);

        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.ref = position;

    holder.txtname.setText(string_myeventref[position]);
    holder.edtxtvalue.setText(string_myeventref_value[position]);

    holder.edtxtvalue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            string_myeventref_value[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
            System.out.println("Text changed: " + arg0.toString());
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtname;
    EditText edtxtvalue;
    int ref;
}
}
```

and in my main class I called it like this:

```
String[] string_myeventref = new String[] {"My Startnumber:", "Total Distance:", "Total Time:"};
String[] string_myeventref_value = new String[] {mER.getBib(), mER.getTotald(), mER.getTotalt()};
adapter = new EventRefAdapter(myeventref.this, string_myeventref, string_myeventref_value);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_eventref);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So my final goal is it, to refill the mER object, well a copy of the original one ;)
Also nice would be, a way to get the value after the editText filed has been left, but I think this doesnt really matter if I write each change or just the complete one.

Thanks md

Update:
I changed my adapter class to this and it seems to work now, have to check it:

```
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = view;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final myeventref.MyEventRefRow item = elements.get(position);

    if (rowView == null) {

        //LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResourceId, null, true);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView_myeventref_name);
        holder.edtxtvalue = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText_myeventref_value);

        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    if (holder.textWatcher != null) {
        holder.edtxtvalue.removeTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher);
    }

    holder.textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            item.setValue(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };
    holder.edtxtvalue.addTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher);

    holder.txtname.setText(item.getName());
    holder.edtxtvalue.setText(item.getValue());

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to have your activity implement an interface with a method such as `void fieldUpdated(int position, String value)`. Then, in `afterTextChanged()`, you could do this:

```java
((MyInterface)context).fieldUpdated(holder.red, arg0.toString());
```

(Note that your implementation of `fieldUpdated` in the main activity will need a reference to the String arrays you want to update, so you might want to make them member variables of the class.)

This is a very simple implementation of what's known as the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Do u mean to change my variable in the class to public so that the interface can reach it?
Maybe I have to place the afterTextChanged() in the main activity but if I remember correctly, I received a nullpointer